# Can you use a nth-child selector on a previously cached jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When working with the DOM, I tend cache an item, detect if it is present, then perform some work. Like so:

```
var $fooModules = $j('.foo-modules');

if ($fooModules .length > 0) {
    //do something.
}
```

But, how do I tackle using a jQuery select like nth-child with my cached selector?

I know I cannot do this:

```
        $j($fooModules:nth-child(3n).addClass('myClass');
```

What do you do, to get around this common problem?

Thanks

-R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter a set down further using a selector or function, like this:

```
$fooModules.filter(":nth-child(3n)").addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: That is awesome. I use "find" all the time, but strangely forgot about the very handy "filter" method. With this example their distinction is very clear to me know. Thank you Nick!